# Getting the parent element with display block

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this html

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
This text is directly under div
<p>Some text under p tag. <span> Some under span tag</span>  and this is another text</p>
<p>Another para</p>
</div>
<button>Get block level parent</button>
```

Javascript

```
function getParentBlock() {
    element = document.getSelection().focusNode;
    while (p = element.parentNode) {
        displaystyle = window.getComputedStyle(p, null).getPropertyValue('display');
        if (displaystyle == 'block') {
            return p;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
}

function alertCurrentParent() {
    alert(getParentBlock());
}
btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.onclick = alertCurrentParent;
```

The jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/shankardevy/aA8Kb/

Now when I place the cursor inside the text 'Another Para' or doubleclick the 'Another Para' (which in my mac selects the whole para) and click the button 'Get block level parent', I get HTMLParagraphElement in alert.

However, when I place the cursor in first para ("Some text under p tag"), and I click the button, I get "HTMLParagraphElement" in alert. And when I double click the second para which selects the entire first paragraph, and click the button, I get "HTMLDivElement".

I want my code to work as in the second paragraph. i.e., double click the sentence and click the button, it should show me "HTMLParagraphElement". How do I do that?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you start your loop with the parent node. When you select the entire paragraph, its parent is the `DIV`. So start your loop at the current element instead of the parent.

```
function getParentBlock() {
    var element = document.getSelection().focusNode;
    for (var p = element; p; p = p.parentNode) {
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(p, null);
        if (style) {
            var displaystyle = style.getPropertyValue('display');
            if (displaystyle == 'block') {
                return p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/aA8Kb/4/)

You have to test the result of `getComputedStyle` before calling getPropertyValue, because text nodes don't have a style and it returns `null`.

Comment: thank you @barmar. Your code works beautifully. But, maybe this is unrelated to your code, but still a bug. see the updated http://jsfiddle.net/shankardevy/aA8Kb/5/ when I double click the first paragraph and click the button, it shows me the content of the second paragraph, which is odd. can you help me debug this?

Comment: changing focusNode to anchorNode resolves the issue. However, I am still puzzled if there is any logic behind why the bug happens with focusNode i.e., the selection made by doubleclick still shows the first paragraph but then why does the focusNode point to the second paragraph?

Comment: `focusNode` is where the selection ends. I guess when you select an entire paragraph, it ends at the beginning of the next one.